# Argparse with spaces

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following script:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--arg1',  dest='arg1')
parse_results = parser.parse_known_args(['--arg1 = value'])
```

However I get the result:

```
(Namespace(arg1=None), ['--arg1 = value'])
```

Is there a way using argparse to accept this kind of input where there are spaces between argument, = and the value?

Answer (score 1):

The shell processes your argument list before your program ever runs, and that processing is very simple: treat each white-space separated word following the command name as a separate argument. By that logic, `--foo = bar` is 3 separate arguments, so `sys.argv` contains `["--foo", "=", "bar"]`. There's no avoiding that, since it happens before `argparse` ever runs.

Given this fact, there's no benefit to writing `--foo = bar`, since it would be equivalent to `--foo=bar` or `--foo bar`, just with extraneous characters (spaces in the first case, `=` in the second).

As to why `--foo=bar` is supported at all when it is equivalent to `--foo bar`, I don't know. It might just be for compatibility with existing practice; it might be useful with different argument parsers, but `argparse` doesn't seem to need it. At some point in the past, I thought I had come up with a reason why being able to specify the argument to `--foo` using one shell word instead of two was useful, but I seem to have forgotten it.

Comment: Long argument syntax was introduced for convenience and readability. The syntax `--foo=bar` exists because it's unambiguous. If I see `--foo bar` in a script and want to know whether `bar` is a program argument or the value of `-foo`, I need to read the manual.

Comment: I've never found that reason terribly compelling; how often is it useful to know if `--foo` is taking an argument if you don't already know what it means? If `--foo` is defined with `nargs='?'`, I could imagine that `--foo=` could be used to unambigously indicate that `--foo` is being used without an argument when it is followed by another word. However, `argparse` treats `--foo=` the same as `--foo ""`.

Comment: Quite often, I believe. We read code (including shell scripts) far more often than we write it. The `=` syntax is unambiguous and eliminates the need to guess.

Comment: No, my point is: now you know that `--foo=bar` means that `bar` is the argument to `--foo`. Great! But you still have to look up what it *means* to pass `bar` as an argument to `foo`. I agree it's more readable; it just doesn't seem to be any more *functional*. I'd be happier knowing that there was something you could *do* with the equal sign that is much harder, or impossible, to do without it.

Comment: Well, you can support optional arguments (by forbidding the `--opt arg` syntax). Personally I think clarity is the more important benefit.

Comment: I look at `--arg1=value` as a long name form of `-avalue`.  `argparse` is building on precedents set by `optparse`, `getopt`, and other `unix` parsers.  `optparse` allows `=`.

Answer (score 0):

It's about how the shell parses arguments:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ cat argz.py
import sys
print "args:",  sys.argv
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python argz.py --foo = bar --bar=baaz
args: ['argz.py', '--foo', '=', 'bar', '--bar=baaz']
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, a problem with your code: A program will see space-separated components as separate arguments. Your example should have read

```
parse_results = parser.parse_known_args(['--arg1', '=', 'value'])
```

or you can use `split()` to generate the array on the fly, as the documentation does it:

```
parse_results = parser.parse_known_args('--arg1 = value'.split())
```

The above still doesn't give you want you want:

```
>>> parser.parse_known_args('--arg1 = value'.split())
(Namespace(arg1='='), ['value'])
```

The equals-sign is parsed as the argument, because long argument syntax is either `--option=value` or `--option value`. The `=` sign is only there to separate the option name from its argument; there is no point in including it if arguments are separated by spaces, so the syntax `--option = value` is not supported.

Recommendation: Use only standard long-argument syntax, i.e. `--arg1 value` or `--arg=value`.

But if you absolutely must support the form `--arg1 = value`, you can filter the argument list to throw out elements that are a single `=` sign.:

```
>>> cleanup = lambda args: (a for a in args if a != '=')
>>> parser.parse_known_args(cleanup('--arg1 = value'.split()))
(Namespace(arg1='value'), [])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
parser.parse_known_args(['--arg1 = value'])
```

it's equivalent to the commandline:

```
$myfun.py '--arg1 = value'
```

In both cases `--arg1 = value` is treated as one string.  Since it does not match `'--arg1'` or `'--arg1='` it goes into the unrecognized strings list.

As others have pointed out, without the quotes `$myfun.py --arg1 = value` passes to the parser as `['--arg1', '=', 'value']`.  Which would parse to:

```
(Namespace(arg1='='), ['value'])
```

If `--arg` is defined with `nargs='+'`, then you'd get

```
(Namespace(arg1=['=', 'value']), [])
```

and you could ignore the '='.

But for sake of consistency with other commandline practices, I'd suggest sticking with the `--arg1=value`, and `--arg1 value` syntax.